# Unknown option: %{strftime("%c")}%=0x%B\\

Tags: vim

I have write the code according to book**learning vi and vim** p202

```
set statusline=%<%t%h%m%r\ \ %a\  %{strftime(\"%c\")}%=0x%B\
      \\  line:%1,\   \ col:%c%V\ %P
```

i write the sentence in my _vimrc ,when i open a file ,an mistake occur .

```
Unknown option: %{strftime("%c")}%=0x%B\\
```

what is the matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just before the `%{strftime`, you have *two space characters*, and only the first one is properly escaped with `\`. Therefore, Vim thinks the option value ends there and another option name begins. You need to either remove that additional space, or escape it (same for later occurrences of multiple spaces):

```
set statusline=%<%t%h%m%r\ \ %a\ \ %{strftime(\"%c\")}%=0x%B\
    \\ \ line:%1,\ \ \ \ col:%c%V\ %P
```

As this is cumbersome and hard to read and edit, an **alternative** is to use `:let`, which avoids that escaping:

```
let &statusline = '%<%t%h%m%r  %a  %{strftime("%c")}%=0x%B  line:%1,    col:%c%V %P'
```

Comment: You can also set local values of options (like `:setlocal`) with `:let &l:opt = ...`.